# Public __Construct Session Error Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter when I add a if statement to my **user library** public construct area it now shows sessions as a blank array().

**With if statement** Unable to display sessions with if statement in **public construct**

```
Array
(
)
```

**Without if statement**

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => ********
    [ip_address] => ********
    [user_agent] => ********
    [last_activity] => ********
    [user_data] => 
)
```

When I remove the if statement for public construct area session comes back.

I need to be able to have my if statement working in my public construct area.

```
public function __construct() {
$this->CI =& get_instance();
$this->CI->load->database();
$this->CI->load->library('session');
$this->CI->load->library('form_validation');
$this->CI->load->library('security/encryption');
if(null !== ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'))) {

  $username = $this->CI->input->post('username');
  $password = $this->CI->input->post('password');
  $this->CI->db->select('user_id');
  $this->CI->db->from('user');
  $this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
  $this->CI->db->where('password',  hash('sha512', $password));
  $this->CI->db->where('status', "1");
  $user_query = $this->CI->db->get();
  if($user_query->num_rows) {
    $this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
    $this->username = $this->CI->input->post('username');

    $this->CI->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user SET ip = '" . $this->CI->input->ip_address() . "' WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') . "'");

   } else {
     $this->logout();
   }
  }
}
```

**User Lib**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users {

      public function __construct() {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->CI->load->database();
            $this->CI->load->library('session');
            $this->CI->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->CI->load->library('security/encryption');
            if(null !== ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'))) {

                  $username = $this->CI->input->post('username');
                  $password = $this->CI->input->post('password');
                  $this->CI->db->select('user_id');
                  $this->CI->db->from('user');
                  $this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
                  $this->CI->db->where('password',  hash('sha512', $password));
                  $this->CI->db->where('status', "1");
                  $user_query = $this->CI->db->get();
                  if($user_query->num_rows) {
                        $this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
                        $this->username = $this->CI->input->post('username');

                        $this->CI->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user SET ip = '" . $this->CI->input->ip_address() . "' WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') . "'");

                  } else {
                        $this->logout();
                  }
            }
      }

      public function login() {
            $username = $this->CI->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->CI->input->post('password');

            $this->CI->db->select('user_id');
            $this->CI->db->from('user');
            $this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->CI->db->where('password',  hash('sha512', $password));
            $this->CI->db->where('status', "1");
            $user_query = $this->CI->db->get();

            if($user_query->num_rows() == 1) {
                  $this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
                  $this->username = $this->CI->input->post('username');

                  $data = array(
                        'isLogged' => $this->user_id,
                        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
                        'username' => $this->CI->input->post('username')
                  );
                  $this->CI->session->set_userdata($data);

                  return true;
            } else {
                  return false;
            }
      }

      public function logout() {
            $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
      }

      public function isLogged() {
            return $this->user_id;
      }

     public function getId() {
            return $this->user_id;
      }

      public function getUserName() {
            return $this->username;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out gave this a try below and now working.

```
if(null !== ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'))) {
              $this->CI->db->select('user_id');
              $this->CI->db->from('user');
              $this->CI->db->where('status', "1");
              $user_query = $this->CI->db->get();
              if($user_query->num_rows) {

                    $this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');

                    $this->CI->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user SET ip = '" . $this->CI->input->ip_address() . "' WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') . "'");

              } else {
                    $this->logout();
              }
        }
```